# Modern transparent folder compression in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: storage, samba, network-share, compression, ubuntu-18.04

I'm looking for a way to transparently compress files in a directory, that will be shared over SMB.

I have a server, running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and I use it for file storage. Mainly what I want to do is transparently compress a folder containing ISO files so that they can be read by any computer on my network, without that computer even knowing they are compressed.

I CANNOT compress the ISO files themselves, for example into a .7z archive, or a .cso file, as they're PS2 ISO files that can only be streamed to a modded PS2 as ISO files, and not compressed. I've tried to compile both versions of fusecompress [tex](https://github.com/tex/fusecompress) AND [hexxellor](https://github.com/hexxellor/fusecompress) both REFUSE to compile on my system, despite having all the packages needed, and following a few different guides. [Like this one, for example.](http://srinathh.github.io/blog/fusecompress-on-ubuntu/)

I've seen guides on how to use programs like archivemount to mount a compressed archive as r/w, but I don't like the way they operate. They don't do the compression on-the-fly, and instead wait until you unmount the archive. I would like a way to do it seamlessly, the way NTFS compression works on Windows PCs. I've read that btrfs doesn't work well on the current kernel >4.0, and it's already an ext4 partition.

It's an LVM volume over 3 disks, used solely for storage capacity, and ZFS probably wouldn't like it very much.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like a way to do it seamlessly, the way NTFS compression works on Windows PCs.

If that's your requirement, then you require a filesystem that supports native compression.  That means ZFS or BTRFS, unless you think Reiser4 is still supported to your satisfaction.

Your current LVM/ext4 configuration does not support your stated requirement.

Either abandon the requirement or the configuration.

Comment: How would I go about converting the ext4 partition to BTRFS? Is there a program I can use, or will I have to do it all manually?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is read only (you're talking about ISO images, which are read only), you may use [SquashFS](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/squashfs.html). It is like mountable .tar.xz. There is an in-kernel driver which requires root permissions to mount, and also FUSE driver which has less performance but it makes an ordinary user to be able to mount.